# ANTLR Grammar Mutually Left Recursive

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I do know that this question has been asked a lot of times. I am trying to build a grammar using ANTLR.

```
Predicate           : LOWERCASE | Predicate VarChars ;

VarChars            : LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE;

fragment LOWERCASE  : [a-z] ;   

fragment UPPERCASE  : [A-Z] ;
```

I am getting the following error :"The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [Predicate]"

Please show me how this is fixed. How to remove the mutual left recursion in my antlr grammar.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? is your intention that a predicate must always start with a small letter? could you give an example of some valid/invalid tokens? the technical reason of the error message is of course that Predicate occurs as its own rule alternative.

Comment: So This is a part of Datalog Grammar. 

pA would be valid
PA would be invalid

I got the mutually left recursive error for many cases. How do I fix the error? How can I use Predicate in its own rule alternative

Comment: Be aware that rules starting with a capital letter are lexer rules. To avoid confusion, the practice is to give an all uppercase name. What you probably want is : `PREDICATE
    :   LOWERCASE ( LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE )* ;`. And you must provide another rule for input like `PA`, or you'll have token recognition errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the recursive occurrence of "Predicate" altogether. VarChars alone is sufficient to mean lowercase or uppercase. Use the + suffix to indicate "one or more instances":

```
fragment LOWERCASE : [a-z];   
fragment UPPERCASE : [A-Z];

VARCHARS  : LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE;
PREDICATE : LOWERCASE VARCHARS+;
```

Applied to your examples, this would disqualify "p" and "PA" as predicates, and qualify "pA".

Observe how `PREDICATE` and `VARCHARS` are still lexer rules (as opposed to syntactical rules) as they describe how a lexeme is formed. Therefore it follows the all-uppercase naming convention (Antlr does not care, but it improves readability).