# Antlr Grammar Token not being recognized

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, datalog

Hello I need help with antlr4 grammar. I have been trying to create a parser for Datalog grammar. This is just a small snippet of the whole code. Whatever I try to parse its being recognized as Uppercase or Lowercase. The predicate token is not being recognized

For example the following Code should parse

```
abc as abc-> predicate
```

But its being parsed as

```
a-> Lrr

b-> Lrr

c-> Lrr
```

Its being parsed similarly for the rest of my code. How do I fix it?

```
grammar D;



predicate           : Lrr | predicate varChars ;

varChars            : Lrr | Urr;

Lrr : LOWERCASE;

Urr: UPPERCASE;

fragment LOWERCASE  : [a-z] ;

fragment UPPERCASE  : [A-Z] ;
```

Where am I going wrong. Please help

Comment: You'll probably have an easier time if you define your token rules, so that "abc", "as" and "abc" are the tokens in your example. At the token level ambiguities are resolved by always preferring the longest match, which seems like what you want here.

Comment: How do I define token rules?

Comment: Token rules are the ones whose names start with capital letters (`Lrr` and `Urr` in your code). I'm saying you should define those to match more than a single letter.

Comment: About the same grammar as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47153634/antlr-grammar-mutually-left-recursive). `predicate` has no sense, it does the same as `predicate : LOWERCASE  ( LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE )?`. Is predicate just any word starting with a lower letter ?